# Keystore path does not work

Tags: android, certificate, apk, android-keystore

I have a huge problem. I created an app and want to update it with a new version (1.1). When I start to generate a signed APK I choose the old keystore path but the key password is incorrect. I don't know why because I have only one password for my applications and IT stuff. Is there any other possibility to generate the same certificate? Or do I have to create it as a new app?

Comment: You will need new certificate now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nature of the signed APK is to prevent people who don't know the password from compiling your app and releasing it.  This is a security measure to protect you from malicious developers.

The unfortunate side effect of this great feature is that if you forget your password, you cannot compile your app with the same certificate.

So unless you can find that original password, you will have to create a new certificate.  And this time, remember your password.  :)

Comment: Ok thank you :) When I deactivate the apk in the play store and upload a new one with an other certificate its like a new store entry?

Comment: The store will not treat it as a "version upgrade".  It will see it as a whole new APK.  But your store listing will still be valid.  Or, rather, it should be.  If not, you may have to make a new listing, and point to it from your old listing.